# Specific directories for clients

Tags: linux, ftp, tftp

I have a TFTP server with some clients (let's say that A B C D are the clients). All the clients must have the same configuration (only the server IP). But, some clients must fetch files in a specific directory, and others in other directories. For example, A and B have to fetch files in `/tftp/1` and C, D in `/tftp/2`.

The best would be using IP address and subnets to make the distinction ("all the clients in this subnet fetch in this directory"), but I don't know if TFTP can do that.

PS : I don't use TFTP by choice, and I can't use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

1. From TFTP protocol ([RFC 1350](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1350.txt))

   > Security Considerations
   >
   > Since TFTP includes no login or access control mechanisms, care
   >   must    be taken in the rights granted to a TFTP server process so as
   >   not to    violate the security of the server hosts file system.  TFTP
   >   is often    installed with controls such that only files that have
   >   public read    access are available via TFTP and writing files via
   >   TFTP is    disallowed.

   Then the protocol itself has no support for your needs.
2. You can use a particular TFTP server supporting your needs i.e. **tftpd-hpa**. This Server implements a feature called **"Filename Remapping"**; The  **--map-file** option specifies a file which contains filename remapping rules. The set of rules processes every request and i.e. based on the requester's IP redirects the request to i.e. a particular directory. See tftpd-hpa man pages.

Comment: This is a good answer (the point 2 is what I was looking for, and I'm already using tftpd-hpa), but not _the_ good answer.
I can specify a sub directory using file-remapping and the IP address of the client ; but I can't specify a sub directory for a few clients (and not a sub dir by client). I'm still looking at it.